# Not getting a response when I should be getting it from API?

Tags: api, mocha.js, supertest

I am using mocha for getting the response of this API: "http://reqres.in/api/users?page=1"

I am getting a response when I use this request in POSTMAN:
[image]

However when using the same request in mocha to get a response (token in this case). I am getting an empty reponse.
Below is the code I wrote and the output in Terminal:

```
    const mocha = require ('mocha');
    const should = require ('should');
    const supertest = require('supertest');


   let baseUrl = supertest("http://reqres.in/");
   let listUserEndPoint = 'api/users?page=1';

    it("List User", async function() {
    let res = await baseUrl.get(listUserEndPoint)
         .set('Content-Type',  'application/json') // Setting the content type as header
    console.log(res.body);

    });
```

[image: Terminal ouptut]

Can someone help me out, what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You haven't specified any headers. How are you supposed to log in then? I am guessing if you spit out the headers on the response object in the console you would see something like a HTTP 400 Forbidden response.

Comment: @oligofren thanks for pointing it out, that API worked by setting the header, however I have edited my question and this API still gives an empty response even after setting the header, can you please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I debugged this while sitting on the subway and looking at the response. Open this [running example on RunKit](https://runkit.com/fatso83/lazy-ass-programmer). Expand the response object and look at the headers. You'll see that you get a redirect to the HTTPS version (HTTP 301). That's why it works in the browser. So just replace http with https.